# Python: Object destruction upon terminal close

Tags: python

I need to create a code that would be flexible enough to perform some required cleanups even if the terminal where it was running is closed or SSH connection is lost. I have all the necessary code wrapped into one class' `__del__` method. However, Python doesn't seem to be calling it (unlike C++) on exit. I tried `[atexit][1]` but it wasn't called either.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You probably don't need to do anything.

Comment: @Marcin: why I don't need to do anything? The lock stays held.

Comment: What lock? You haven't told us anything about why you want to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `signal` module. `SIGHUP` should be sent to your program on either closing the terminal window or losing the SSH connection. You could catch `SIGINT` instead of `SIGHUP` but this is a catch-all solution.

```
import signal
import sys
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print 'Handling SIGHUP signal!'
    sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGHUHP, signal_handler)
print 'Waiting for SIGHUP'
signal.pause()
```

You can test this by issuing `sudo kill -1 <pid of your python process>` in another terminal window.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I put handlers for all signals except SIGHUP.